# Putting the cursor in a specific place in a live template

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm

I just wanted to know how you put a cursor in a specific place in a live template for IntelliJ

For example:

```
# $var$ is an insance of the $objectType$ class
assert isinstance($var$, $objectType$)$END$
```

What happens here is that your cursor gets dragged to `$var$` in the comment string first and then to your other values inside assert. What I wanted to know is how you chose where the cursor goes first.

I've read the documentation, but this is not mentioned, although a lot of other things are.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can arrange the order that your variables are visited in. You find the information under bullet number five in this IntelliJ help document: http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/creating-and-editing-template-variables.html

> To arrange variables in the order you want IntelliJ IDEA to switch between associated input fields, use the **Move Up** and **Move Down** buttons.

---

**Edit**

You have to update the macro definition to similar to this:

```
# $varComment$ is an insance of the $objectTypeComment$ class
assert isinstance($var$, $objectType$)$END$
```

And then you define the order **and** expression to something like this (I didn't have any good expression for the `var` and `orderType` for you):

[image]

Since you fill in the `Skip if defined` for the two comment variable they will just take the values from the `var` and `orderType` and fill it in. This will do *exactly* what you are looking for :-)

Comment: Not what I was looking for. If you created something like this, since I'm using the same var names, because I want an extra comment, what it does is, go to the comment first. I know you can re-arrange, but I cannot control where the pointer goes first. The main problem lies in the notion that I am naming my vars the same. Sublime text actually has a better snippet tooling system.

Comment: @GamesBrainiac Sorry for that. I didn't really understand your problem at the beginning. Now with my update you will see that this will solve your problem completely.

Comment: Thanks for this man, I appreciate it. Although it does solve my problems, it does not solve the problems of telling the template where to put my cursor first, if no other answers come after a day or two, I'll accept your answer. Thanks a lot for this man! :D

Comment: @Games Where exactly do you want the cursor then? It is now placed on the first item in the list of variables.

Comment: I want to be able to place my cursor by order. For example, I can go like, `$1:var$`, and then `$2:some_other_var$`, and this will control where my cursor is placed.

Comment: @GamesBrainiac I still don't understand. The order is decided by the order of the list from the screenshot I added. How does that differ from what you are expecting? You can put the `objectType` after `var` in the list and then the order will (of course) be `objectType -> var`.